# How to know if a CWnd scrollbar is visible?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a custom control that displays images. It displays scroll bar when image exceeds the displayable size. For some reason, I want to know whether a scroll bar horizontal or vertical is displayed or not. I can't find any direct functions in `CWnd` class.

I found `GetScrollBarInfo` but had no luck checking that. Here is the code:

```
SCROLLBARIINFO stHSBInfo;
GetScrollBarInfo( this->GetSafeHwnd(), OBJID_HSCROLL, &stHSBInfo );
if(  !( STATE_SYSTEM_INVISIBLE &stHSBInfo.rgstate[0] )) // Always true
{
    // Code
}
```

Please help!

Comment: What is `this`? Which object instance does that point to? You have to pass the `GetScrollBarInfo` function a handle to the window that contains the scroll bar.

Comment: Is the structure being initialized?

Comment: @CodyGray `this` is the window that contains the scrollbar

Comment: @DougRamsey Initialized? Is there anything else to be initialized manually?

Answer (score 0):

Get the size of system scrollbar width with GetSystemMetrics.
Compare the size of your custom control between GetWindowRect and GetClientRect.
If the differences is larger than the size of a scrollbar width, is is visible.

Comment: Umm, what if there's something else *other than a scrollbar* in the non-client area of the window that is taking up that space?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states, "Before calling the `GetScrollBarInfo` function, set `cbSize` to `sizeof(SCROLLBARINFO)`."

Your code should be updated so:

```
SCROLLBARIINFO stHSBInfo;
stHSBInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLBARINFO);
GetScrollBarInfo( this->GetSafeHwnd(), OBJID_HSCROLL, &stHSBInfo );
if(  !( STATE_SYSTEM_INVISIBLE &stHSBInfo.rgstate[0] )) // Always true
{
    // Code
}
```